# Windows Forms - application gradually reacting slower

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have an annoying problem with my Windows Forms C# application.

I'm working on a game, what I've got so far is pretty simple, you can move your pieces according to the game's rules

picture of an example of a single move
[image]

At the beginning of the game,everything works well, the application instantly reacts to my clicks and moves the pieces according to my will immediately.
The problem arises after multiple moves. After about 30 or 40 moves, it takes the application about a second to react to my clicks. This makes the game kind of unplayable, because it reacts extremely slowly. The more moves I make, the slower the application will react.

I'm painting in a Panel (a DoubleBuffered Panel to be more exact). I tried to paint into a PictureBox instead but it did not change anything, the application reacted just as slowly.
It isn't a time issue, I can leave the application opened for minutes and it will still react fast after my first clicks. Also if I open and close the form (not the app, just the form) it starts reacting fast again.

Does anybody know what could be the issue? I'm out of ideas on this one. I would add some code but I don't know what exactly to add. I guess I will just add that after the player clicks either his piece or a possible move, the panel gets refreshed with the Invalidate command.
Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT: Posting some code

```
        private void herniPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            vytvoritPole(e);

            if (kliknutoHracovoPole == true)//draws possible moves and the black circle
            {
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, poz_X_KHr, poz_Y_KHr, sirkaPole, vyskaPole);
                foreach (MoznyTahHrace m in mozneTahyHrace)
                {
                    m.NakresliMozneTahyHrace(e);
                }
                pen.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void vytvoritPole(PaintEventArgs e)//creates the grid
        {
            int poz_X_He = (this.herniPanel.Width / 2) - (sirkaPole / 2);
            int poz_Y_He = 13;

            for (int i = 0; i < pocetPoli; i++)
            {
                Pole pole = new Pole(poz_X_He, poz_Y_He, sirkaPole, vyskaPole);
                herniPole.Add(pole);
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + posun;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 2);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 3);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 8);
                        break;
                    case 22:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 12);
                        break;
                    case 34:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 11);
                        break;
                    case 45:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 10);
                        break;
                    case 55:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 9);
                        break;
                    case 64:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 9);
                        break;
                    case 74:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 10);
                        break;
                    case 85:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 11);
                        break;
                    case 97:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 12);
                        break;
                    case 110:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 8);
                        break;
                    case 114:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 3);
                        break;
                    case 117:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + (posun * 2);
                        break;
                    case 119:
                        poz_Y_He += posun;
                        poz_X_He -= (posun / 2) + posun;
                        break;
                }
                poz_X_He += posun;
            }

            if (inicializace)//only at the beginning of the game, creates 10 player pieces
            {
                inicializace = false;
                for(int i = 0; i < herniPole.Count; i++)
                {
                    Pole pole = (Pole)herniPole[i];
                    poz_X_He = pole.get_poz_X_He();
                    poz_Y_He = pole.get_poz_Y_He();
                    if(poz_Y_He >= posun * 13)
                    {
                        Hrac hrac = new Hrac(poz_X_He, poz_Y_He, sirkaPole, vyskaPole);
                        hracovaPole.Add(hrac);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            foreach (Pole p in herniPole)//draws the game pieces
            {
                p.NakresliPole(e);
            }
            
            foreach (Hrac h in hracovaPole)//draws player's pieces
            {
                h.NakresliHrace(e);
            }
        }

        public void NakresliHrace(PaintEventArgs e)//draws player's pieces, NakresliMozneTahyHrace and NakresliPole work the same way
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.DodgerBlue);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(br, this.poz_X_Hr, this.poz_Y_Hr, this.sirkaPole, this.vyskaPole);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, this.poz_X_Hr, this.poz_Y_Hr, this.sirkaPole, this.vyskaPole);
            br.Dispose();
            pen.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: People have had this problem, so they invented the profiler to see where the code is taking the most time. Also they also had memory problems, so they invented the memory profiler.. My guess is if you ran these and learn to understand the output you would solve your current issues and many more future issues

Comment: I have added the code which draws the features in my post. Thanks for the profiler solution, I will try to work with the profiler to solve the problem.

Comment: Dispose you IDisposable objects. [Pen class is IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I added Dispose to each of my Pens and Brushes (added it to my post as well). It may have reduced the lag a little bit and the process memory is certainly lower, but the application still reacts slower to my moves as I make more of them. Did I not dispose of the pens and brushes correctly? I'm not sure if my solution in the NakresliHrace class is correct or not.

Comment: Everytime you create the grid (on every call to Paint, in the vytvoritPole method) you add elements to herniPole. Do you ever clear this list?

Comment: Is it necessary to create new instances of your pen and brush in your NakresliHrace, especially since their values don't change? Why not create a single instance of them in initialisation (even making them static) - and then dispose of them when closing your app.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. It would appear that I created 121 new elements on every click, so after a certain amount of clicks it started taking a long time to iterate through the cycle. I added this.herniPole.Clear(); before every Invalidate command and the application now works smoothly after arbitrary amount of clicks. Thank you very much, your solution really helped me.